# Why not demand President's/candidate's financial records instead of tax returns?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, taxes

[What significance could the information in Donald Trump's tax return have to his campaign?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/what-significance-could-the-information-in-donald-trumps-tax-return-have-to-his) addresses what information could be gleaned from Donald Trump's tax returns if he allowed them to be released. But I wonder why there's so much focus on the tax returns, rather than other financial records.

While there's certainly some useful information there, and you can get a rough picture of a person's overall financial situation, it's still missing quite a bit. A person or corporation's tax return only reports those aspects of their finances that affect their taxes. For instance, you only have to report investments that produced income that year, as well as investments that you've sold so you can report capital gains and losses.

Why not demand access to candidates' more detailed financial records (e.g. net worth statements, budgets, corporate balance sheets)? Is it simply because there's no requirement that individuals keep detailed personal records like this, but tax returns *are* required, and falsifying them is illegal? But most wealthy people *do* have accountants and money managers who track their finances, so the records most likely exist and they could be requested. And if they have much of their wealth in businesses, like Trump does, those corporations will have detailed books.

Or is it even simpler: is there no law authorizing Congress to demand this information? And in the current political climate, it would be impossible to pass such a law -- the Republican Senate would not vote for it, and even if it did manage to pass, it wouldn't be by a veto-proof super-majority. On the other hand, there's a [1924 law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6103) that allows some congressional committees to obtain the tax returns of any taxpayer, so they go with what they can legally get (Trump is challenging that law, and it will probably end up in the Supreme Court). And even this law doesn't allow the returns to be disclosed publicly, unless the taxpayer consents.

Comment: Frankly we don't have any rights to demand somebody's personal information may it be taxes or balance sheets, it is voluntarily that candidates disclose their taxes, it is a practice now followed.

Comment: @Up-In-Air Actually, there is a 1924 law that allows the House Ways and Means Committee to obtain anyone's tax returns.

Comment: Put that in an answer @Barmar - we'd all like to learn more about this!

Comment: @cyber101 I added a link to the question, it's not really an answer.

Comment: As a practical matter, not everyone has "balance sheets" of any sort, but everyone with income files tax returns.  Compiling a balance sheet might be burdensom (would be for me, anyway), whil supplying copies of tax returns would be as simple as emailing a few pdf files.

Comment: @jamesqf I addressed that in the third paragraph. If you use a program like Quicken to manage your personal finances, it can produce a balance sheet.

Comment: This request is not so shocking - in Poland all our elected politicians and top civil servants are required by law among other to list their all major assets and liabilities, however it does not take form of balance sheet.

Comment: Everyone seems to be focused on "balance sheets", I just meant that as a an example of detailed financial records. I've edited the question to be more general.

Comment: FWIW, something like that is indeed required in some (many?) European countries. Obviously it can be intrusive and burdensome but nobody is forced to run for president.

Comment: @jamesqf If you were running for president, I can't imagine the difficulty of putting together financial records would be a considerable burden next to the effort of campaigning in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar: Sure, IF I used a program like Quicken (or GnuCash: https://www.gnucash.org/ since I don't do Windows).  But I don't, and see no need to.  And yes, if I were running for President, I could probably pay staff to do that sort of thing, but how about my state legislature or county commission?

Comment: @jamesqf We're talking about multi-millionaires, not random county clerks. If you can get by without keeping detailed financial records, there's probably nothing interesting in your finances to begin with. But I doubt that would be the case for anyone running for President, or even Senators. OTOH, AOC was a bartender before she became a Congresswoman -- she might not have any financial records worth reporting (but she has an economics degree and has run a business, so she might keep good personal finances).

Comment: @jamesqf And if you have a significant investment portfolio, you practically have to keep records in order to fill out your tax returns properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another relatively straightforward pragmatic reason is that a tax return is, at some level, an *objective* concept and a formal document; while there are, for instance, [regulatory requirements](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/210.5-02) on what goes into a balance sheet for a corporation, there's no real formal definition of a balance sheet, particularly on a personal level.  Since one of the current fronts in the fight for financial disclosure from candidates is legal (e.g. California's bill SB-27 [requiring tax returns for candidates to appear on a primary ballot](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=201920200SB27)), using a format for that information that's already codified in law makes it much easier to create new legislation requiring that information.

Comment: This is perfect.  I have upvoted accordingly.  I'm deleting my old comments as they are no longer relevant.

Comment: This also seems like a very good reason.

Answer (score 10):

Because there is a [custom](https://www.taxnotes.com/presidential-tax-returns) that presidential candidates share their tax returns.

Most presidential candidates are politicians not business people, so demanding their balance sheets would be meaningless.  Beyond that, the few that have been business people, excepting Donald Trump, have put their money in blind trusts.  With a blind trust, they don't actually know their balance sheet except at the highest level.  And financial disclosures already cover that high level view.

- [Politico](https://www.politico.com/story/2015/07/donald-trump-financial-disclosure-120472)
- [Trump financial disclosure, 2016](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/2838696/Trump-2016-Financial-Disclosure.txt) ([PDF](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/2838696/Trump-2016-Financial-Disclosure.pdf))

Note that they complain about the financial disclosure information being self-reported.  This contrasts with the income tax information, which is usually based on other forms.  E.g. salary information is based on W-2 forms.

Comment: They don't usually put their money in the blind trust until after they're elected, do they?

Comment: Cater was a buisness man (Peanut Farmer) and put his Buisness in a (poorly run) blind trust while he was President.   I'd also like to point out that releasing tax returns is a very new tradition in the Presidential race (I believe it only started after World War II) and was never required by office.

Comment: Also while no President was charged with tax fraud while in office, at least one Vice President (Spiro Agnew) did resign as Vice President after he was charged with Tax Fraud among other crimes, commited while he was governor of Maryland, so there is precedence that any fraud with Trump's taxes would certainly be grounds for his removal from office.   A more benign speculation is that the returns would reveal Trump isn't worth billions and his status as a billionaire was part of his campaign.  It's a crime to the IRS... not the voting public.

Comment: @hszmv Actually even newer than that. Truman released his, but the next was Nixon, and that apparently started the tradition.